# MHA mysql command failed with rc 1:0

Tags: mysql

mysql command failed with rc 1:0

```
Mon Sep  7 22:17:00 2020 - [info]   Executing command : apply_diff_relay_logs --command=test --slave_user='root' --slave_host=192.168.142.134 --slave_ip=192.168.142.134 --slave_port=3306 --workdir=/var/tmp --target_version=5.7.28-log --manager_version=0.58 --relay_log_info=/home/mysql/data/relay-log.info  --relay_dir=/home/mysql/data/  --slave_pass=xxx <br />
Mon Sep  7 22:17:00 2020 - [info]   Connecting to root@192.168.142.134(192.168.142.134:22).. <br />
  Checking slave recovery environment settings..<br />
    Opening /home/mysql/data/relay-log.info ... ok.<br />
    Relay log found at /home/mysql/data, up to mysql-relay-bin.000002<br />
    Temporary relay log file is /home/mysql/data/mysql-relay-bin.000002<br />
    Checking if super_read_only is defined and turned on.. not present or turned off, ignoring.<br />
    Testing mysql connection and privileges..<br />
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.<br />
ERROR 1175 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown error 1175<br />
mysql command failed with rc 1:0!<br />
 at /usr/local/bin/apply_diff_relay_logs line 404.<br />
    main::check() called at /usr/local/bin/apply_diff_relay_logs line 536<br />
    eval {...} called at /usr/local/bin/apply_diff_relay_logs line 514<br />
    main::main() called at /usr/local/bin/apply_diff_relay_logs line 121<br />
Mon Sep  7 22:17:00 2020 - [error][/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2/MHA/MasterMonitor.pm, ln208] Slaves settings check failed!<br />
Mon Sep  7 22:17:00 2020 - [error][/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2/MHA/MasterMonitor.pm, ln416] Slave configuration failed.<br />
Mon Sep  7 22:17:00 2020 - [error][/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2/MHA/MasterMonitor.pm, ln427] Error happened on checking configurations.  at /usr/local/bin/masterha_check_repl line 48.<br />
Mon Sep  7 22:17:00 2020 - [error][/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2/MHA/MasterMonitor.pm, ln525] Error happened on monitoring servers.<br />
Mon Sep  7 22:17:00 2020 - [info] Got exit code 1 (Not master dead).<br />

MySQL Replication Health is NOT OK!<br />
```

Please ask the gods what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you should write what is your target and what problem is making you stuck, **attach the portion of code interested and** also **explain what you've tried to solve the issues**

Comment: Please read how to make a good question article. It will you to understand to how to make a good answer. And don't forget to describe your question to understand your problem.